# Xtext grammar more abstract classes instantiation

Tags: dsl, xtext

I'm doing Expressions DSL using Xtext and I want some classes to inherit from some abstract ones. 
Hierarchy: 
Expression is an abstract class extended by BinaryOperation, UnaryOperation, Number and Atomic. 
BinaryOperation is an abstract class extended by Add, Sub, Mul, Div, Power
UnaryOperation is an abstract class extended by UnaryPlus, UnaryMinus and Factorial.

Whole grammar:

```
Expressions: 
    elements+=EvalExpr;
EvalExpr: 
    'eval' expression=Expression ';';

Expression: AddOrSub;
UnaryOperation:
    Expression;
BinaryOperation:
    Expression;

AddOrSub returns BinaryOperation:
    MulOrDivOrPower (( {Add.left=current} '+' | 
                        {Sub.left=current} '-' 
    )  right=MulOrDivOrPower)*;

MulOrDivOrPower returns BinaryOperation:
    UnaryPlusOrMinus (( {Mul.left=current} '*' | 
                        {Div.left=current} '/' | 
                        {Power.left=current} '^'
    )  right=UnaryPlusOrMinus)*;

UnaryPlusOrMinus returns UnaryOperation:
   '-' {UnaryMinus} expression=Factorial | '+' {UnaryPlus} expression=Factorial | Factorial;

Factorial returns UnaryOperation:
    Atomic ({Factorial.expression=current} '!')?;

Atomic returns Expression:
    '(' Expression ')' | Number;

Number returns Expression:
    {IntConstant} value=INT;
```

But I'm seeing an error: A class may not be a super type of itself. How can I provide such a functionality ?

Comment: you ususally write `XXXX returns Expression:` everywhere.

Comment: => maybe you are at a point where you are better off with a manually maintained (imported) metamodel

Comment: So there’s no option how to do this ? When I want to instantiate e.g. BinaryOperation in order to provide additional functionality on the semantics level ?